# Is it Possible to have Dynamic - On-The-Fly DeploymentItems?

Tags: c#, tdd, mstest, deploymentitem

I want to write tests to check the existance (and other stuff) of certain files that will be shipped with our project.

This is what I have right now:

```
[DeploymentItem("1.pdf")]
[DeploymentItem("2.pdf")]    
public class DoFilesExist
{
    List<string> _Files;

    public DoFilesExist()
    {
        _Files = new List<string>();
        _Files.Add("1.pdf");
        _Files.Add("2.pdf");
    }

    delegate void fileTest(string fileName);

    void Map(fileTest test)
    {
        foreach (string file in _Files)
        {
            test(file);
        }            
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestExists()
    {
        Map( x => Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(x), x + " doesn't exist") );
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I want to add another file to test, I have to add to the [DeploymentItem] and the _Files List

Is there a way to Dynamically Change the DeploymentItems? Or to grab from them during run time.  I will probably end up having over 30 files here, and I do not want two lists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're mainly testing whether `[DeploymentItem]` works... after all - it isn't `[DeploymentItem]` that defines your **actual** deployment.

Personally, this is something I despise about MSTest; .NET projects already **have** a way to define deployment data - the project! By introducing a second method, it introduces both duplication and risk. One of the reasons I use NUnit instead of MSTest, even though I have a VSTS license `</rant>`.

Re the question; you could use reflection to look at the `DeploymentItem` markers, but I'm really not sure what this is testing, other than the test framework itself...

Comment: This simple example is testing the framework...but, I will do more than just an File.Exists() call.  I wanted to simplify the example for the question.

Comment: How do you get the DeploymentItem's through reflection?

Comment: GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DeploymentItemAttribute))

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to put your files into a subdirectory and then you can have the deployment item reference that e.g.

```
[DeploymentItem("files\"]
public class Test
{
}
```

You might need to mark each file with the CopyAlways as well - see the main question for details.